# beautifulsoup get images and google forms

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, google-forms

I am trying to parse the following site using beautiful soup: 
http://www.rishikumar.com/intern.html

I am then trying to send the entire webpage starting after the word "Subject" as the body of an email. I eventually want to automate the sending of an email for any message on this webpage.

I can successfully get the html text and styling but I am not sure how to extract the images as well as the google form at the bottom of the page. The images do not seem to have href's so I don't really know how to go about this.

Is this possible with beautiful soup/is there any other way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Img url`:

http://www.rishikumar.com/uploads/3/3/0/6/3306532/background-images/1586008872.png

`Google form url:`

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSep4Xbkgi5kk_MlupAFqUZuPDASWj95qMy8Y4M1-q2fKhudNw/viewform?embedded=true

I suggest you use F12 analysis page elements, take a look at beautifulsoup document